# Invalid field Email for SObject AggregateResult in VisualForce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I want to display the AggregateResult on my Visualforce page but it is generating the following error `" Invalid field Email for SObject AggregateResult"`

Below is my code:

```cs
public with sharing class searchDuplicate {
public   AggregateResult[] con{get;set;}

public searchDuplicate()
{
    find();
}
public void find(){
   con = [select Email from Contact group by Email having count(Email) > 1];
    System.debug(con);
}
}
```

Below is my **visualforce** page code:

```cs
<apex:page controller="searchDuplicate">
<apex:pageBlock title="Searching for Duplicate Contacts Record"> 
</apex:pageBlock>
<apex:pageBlock title="Contacts">
    <apex:dataTable value="{!con}" var="c" border="2" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
        <apex:column headerValue="Email" value="{!c['Email']}" />
    </apex:dataTable>
</apex:pageBlock>     
</apex:page>
```

kindly Make a correction if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public with sharing class searchDuplicate {
public  list <con> conList{get;set;}

public class con{
   public string Email {get;set;}
   public con( string email){
      this.Email = email;
   }
}
public searchDuplicate()
{
    find();
}
public void find(){
conList = new  list <con>();  
for( AggregateResult ar : [select Email from Contact group by Email having count(Email) > 1];){ conList.add(new con(string.valueOf(ar.get('Email'))))  } 

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate results (and their fields/columns) come as generic Objects, not sObjects. Therefore there's no obj.get('somefieldname') you can call on them.

Your best option might be to make a helper class that has `String email; Integer count;` fields and loop through the query results populating a list of objects of this helper class.

You could also use `Map<String, Integer>` but that'd come to VF as not sorted alphabetically.

See https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7412/count-a-grouped-by-soql if you need a code sample.

Answer (score 0):

Although the other answers are correct in solving your problem, what you have is actually a bug in SalesForce.

The way to resolve this without creating a custom object is to separate the  into two - The "headerValue" and "value" both being set cause this error.

You want to change it to this:

```
<apex:dataTable value="{!con}" var="c" border="2" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
    <apex:column headerValue="Email" >
        <apex:outputText>{!c['Email']}</apex:outputText>
    </apex:column>
</apex:dataTable>
```

Thanks,
Michael